# Search HTML for specific class name begginings

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to search all elements for a classname of "swa-comp-name".

How would I:
Search my page for elements with the class beginning with swa-comp and get the name after it

Comment: Please review your question - your question title as **zero** relevance to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` and `map`:

```js
const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="swa-comp-"]')].map(element => {
  return element.className.slice(9);
});
console.log(names);
```

```html
<div class="swa-comp-x1"></div>
<div class="swa-comp-x2"></div>
<div class="swa-comp-x3"></div>
<div class="swa-comp-x4"></div>
```

Comment: Kudos for no jQuery.